# TypeError: unhashable type when using Yelp and Twitter API and Markov Bot

Tags: python, twitter, yelp

I'm trying to make a bot that will take the first 140 characters of a review in Yelp and tweet it at 1 hour intervals. I am able to retrieve the the general information from Yelp however, when I try to post it I just get the error "TypeError: unhashable type". I assume it has something to do with the fact that Python cannot read from the list provided by Yelp but am not sure. In its current state, my code is only written to provide the information about the business and not the review specifically so if someone could help me out with that too that would be great.

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
def tweetResponse(resp):
tweet = resp
print (tweet[0:140])

access_token = (omitted)
access_token_secret = (omitted)
consumer_key = (omitted)
consumer_secret = (omitted)

economistbot.twitter_login(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
targetstring = None
keywords = None
prefix = None
suffix = None
maxconvdepth = 5

economistbot.twitter_tweeting_start(days=0,hours=1,minutes=0,keywords=None,prefix = None,suffix='#EconomistBot')
time.sleep(20)
pass
```

2.

```
def main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-q', '--term', dest='term', default=DEFAULT_TERM,
                    type=str, help='Search term (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', dest='location',
                    default=DEFAULT_LOCATION, type=str,
                    help='Search location (default: %(default)s)')

input_values = parser.parse_args()

try:
    resp = query_api(input_values.term, input_values.location)
    print "test"
    print resp
    tweetResponse(resp)
except urllib2.HTTPError as error:
    sys.exit(
        'Encountered HTTP error {0} on {1}:\n {2}\nAbort program.'.format(
            error.code,
            error.url,
            error.read(),
        )
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

and here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rayyanmerchant/Desktop/ChatBots/YelpTwitBOt", line 181, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/rayyanmerchant/Desktop/ChatBots/YelpTwitBOt", line 169, in main
  tweetResponse(resp)
  File "/Users/rayyanmerchant/Desktop/ChatBots/YelpTwitBOt", line 20, in 
tweetResponse
print (tweet[0:140])
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What does `type(tweet)` outputs?

Comment: I can't seem to find type(tweet) but print(tweet) is supposed to output the tweet to console and I guess it takes the tweet and figures out how to tweet it from there. I'm not too familiar with either of the APIs so I don't really know exactly what's going on. Sorry :/ @ViníciusAguiar